# TF2 throws rclcpp::exceptions::RCLInvalidROSArgsError when Pytorch libraries are linked

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to integrate pytorch into my ROS 2 galactic node but have encountered an issue. When the executable gets to this line in my code:

```
_tf_buffer = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(this->get_clock());
_transform_listener = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*_tf_buffer);  # specifically this line
```

It throws a run time error:

```
what():  failed to parse arguments: Couldn't parse remap rule: '-r __node:=transform_listener_impl_563,a2c,cfa,cc0'. Error: Expected lexeme type (1) not found, search ended at index 35, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rcl-3.1.3/src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c:233, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rcl-3.1.3/src/rcl/arguments.c:371
```

I did a test where I added these lines to CMakeLists.txt to another package utilizing TF2:

```
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```

and the same error message appeared. I didn't change the package source files except modifying the CMakeLists.txt file.

For some reason, the act of linking pytorch libraries breaks TF2. I don't understand what the error message means so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's something resembling a stack trace. Nothing stands out to me for what could cause this message:

geometry2/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp
54 [rclcpp::Node::make_shared()](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/2687a3543bf61481b06dcf37839c7e92bed85d2e/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp#L54)

rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp
143 [Node::Node](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/galactic/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp#L143)
151 [get_rcl_node_options()](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/galactic/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp#L151)

rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_options.cpp
94 [get_rcl_node_options](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/galactic/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_options.cpp#L94)
120 [rcl_parse_arguments()](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/galactic/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_options.cpp#L120)

rcl/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c
248 [rcl_parse_arguments](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L248)
363 [_rcl_parse_remap_rule()](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L363)
1827 [_rcl_parse_remap_rule](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L1827)
1850 [_rcl_parse_remap_begin_remap_rule()](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L1850)
1618 [_rcl_parse_remap_begin_remap_rule](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L1618)
1666 [rcl_lexer_lookahead2_expect()](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/arguments.c#L1666)

rcl/rcl/src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c
222 [rcl_lexer_lookahead2_expect](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c#L222)
233 [rcl_lexer_lookahead2_peek()](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/galactic/rcl/src/rcl/lexer_lookahead.c#L233)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403755/tf2-throws-rclcpp::exceptions::rclinvalidrosargserror-when-pytorch-libraries-are-linked/) by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2022-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution to the issue. I dug into the source of geometry2. transform_listener_impl_563,a2c,cfa,cc0 shouldn't have commas in it. For whatever reason, the presence of pytorch libraries causes string formatters to insert commas.

So when pytorch isn't linked, `sstream << "transform_listener_impl_" << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(this);` generates a string `transform_listener_impl_563a2ccfacc0`, but with it linked, it generates `transform_listener_impl_563,a2c,cfa,cc0` which causes the rcl arg parser to freak out.

My solution was to avoid using C++ streams and modify the geometry2 source code:

```
  char node_name[64];
  sprintf(node_name, "transform_listener_impl_%lx", reinterpret_cast<size_t>(this));
```

---

Originally posted by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) with karma: 78 on 2022-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-07-14**:
Wow, that's a nasty side effect the pytorch linking that changes the stringstream std::hex basefield formatting. I can't find a comma separated option in ios_base: https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/ They might be somehow overloading or replacing the implementation in a not so nice way. That's probably worth a ticket on pytorch. Can you isolate that down to a smaller example? Such as just a stringstream in main?

**Comment by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on 2022-07-14**:
Sure! I'll post a file when I can.

**Comment by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on 2022-07-14**:
I have a mini example here:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/81543

Interestingly, it seems the call to .str() produces the commas. It doesn't happen when you pipe it straight to cout.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-07-15**:
Wow, nice job tracking this down to a very minimal example!